# Ruby on Rails how to use form input in another method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, controller

I am working on a hotdesking app where the users would check_availability (check_availability.html.erb) of the desks based on the date range chosen and choose from a list of available desk (new.html.erb) before it gets saved in the database.

How can i use the form input in check_availability and use it under my 'new' method?

bookings_controller.rb

```html
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
 
 def index
 end
  
 def check_availability
 end

 def new
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
  @booking.date_range(params[:book_from], params[:book_to])
 end

 def create
 end

 def show
 end

 private

 def booking_params
  params.permit(:book_from, :book_to, :wing, :section, :number, :user_id)
 end
end
```

booking.rb

```html
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
 belongs_to :desk, optional: true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :desk, allow_destroy: true
 cattr_accessor :current_user
 attr_accessor :book_from, :book_to

 def check_availability
  counter = 0
  Booking.all.each do |b|
   current_date = Date.today
   booked_start_date = b.book_from
   booked_end_date = b.book_to
   if b.user_id == current_user.id && current_date <= booked_end_date && booked_start_date <= current_date
    counter += 1
   end
  end
  puts counter
 end
 
 def date_range(book_from, book_to)
  a = []
  a.push(book_from)
  a.push(book_to)
  puts a
 end
```

routes.rb

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_scope :user do
   authenticated :user do
    root 'bookings#index', as: :authenticated_root
   end

   unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
   end
  end

  devise_for :users
  
  resources :desks

  post '/users/:user_id/bookings/:id', :to => 'bookings#show'
  post '/users/:user_id/bookings/new', :to => 'bookings#new'

  resources :users do
    resources :bookings do
      collection do
        get :check_availability
      end
    end
  end
end
```

check_availability.html.erb

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <h1>Check Availability</h1><hr />
      </div>

      <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <%= form_tag new_user_booking_path, multipart: true do %> 
          <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='not-bold'><%= label_tag :book_from, "Book From" %>: </span></br>
            <span class='date-select'><%= date_select :book_from, class:  'form-control' %></span>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='not-bold'><%= label_tag :book_to, "Book To" %>: </span><br />
            <span class='date-select'><%= date_select :book_to, class:  'form-control' %></span>
          </div>

          <%= submit_tag "Check Availability", class: "btn" %>
          <% end %>
      </div>

  <br />

<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
  <br /> 
  <hr />
    <button type="button" class="button">
      <%= link_to "My Bookings", authenticated_root_path %>
    </button>
    
    <button type="button" class="button">
      <%= link_to "Book Desk", new_user_booking_path(current_user) %>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use `check_avalability.html.erb` in multiple views, include it in a partial. Create a view `views/bookings/new.html.erb`, create a route path in `route.rb` `get '/bookings/new', => 'bookings#new'` or use `resources :bookings`. Inside the view new.html.erb you can `render` the partial

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioBertoglio! It was a routing issue. I changed the `form_tag` route in my `check_availability.html.erb` file to `<%= form_tag(new_user_booking_path, method: "get", class: "bookings") do %> ` and i can now access the form inputs through the controller with params.

Comment: Yes, right. That was the real problem. Your form should do a `GET` request instead of a `PUT` request. Actually I understand this now and Thanks for explaining it to me. I totally think you should give yourself an answer, it can be useful for many of us and If you have additional problem write it down in this discussion as I may have similar too!

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I am still very new to coding and stackoverflow! I just posted an answer. I am actually still struggling to understand routing especially in a nested resources. So now i am trying to save my form in "new" and show the booking details on "show". `<%= form_tag user_booking_path(current_user.id, :id), multipart: true do %>` returns `/users/2/bookings/id`. Any idea how i should resolve this? It should be `/users/:user_id/bookings/:id`.

Comment: I am not sure of the problem you are having. Usually this are the step that you should have:
1. GET request for "/booking/new"  => "bookings#new"
2. POST request "booking" => "bookings#create"
With the post request you save to the database your details
3. GET request "booking/:id" => "bookings#show"
Hear you have the show request

I think with nested resource it is just the same. The best thing you can do is rewrite your question with clear explanation of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Will try it out and post as a new question if i cant solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me lots of tries to figure this out!

I realised it was a routing issue. The form should be doing a `GET` instead of a `PUT` request.

I changed the form_tag route in my `check_availability.html.erb` file to `<%= form_tag(new_user_booking_path, method: "get", class: "bookings") do %>` and i can now access the form inputs through the controller with params.